# NullPointerException on FakeApplication start

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception, playframework-2.1

I'm writing unit tests for a web app and using the Java Play! (2.1.3) framework's FakeApplication class.

```
public class TagTest {
    public static FakeApplication app;    
...
    // BeforeClass only runs once before any tests are run
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
        // Set up new FakeApplication before running any tests
        app = Helpers.fakeApplication(Helpers.inMemoryDatabase());
        Helpers.start(app);
    }
...
}
```

I have the same setUpBeforeClass() method in all four of my test classes that test each of my four different models but when I run the *play test* command, all four test classes return a similar error:

```
[error] Test models.TagTest failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
[error]     at Global.onStart(Global.java:59)
[error]     at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:17)
[error]     at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:175)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:68)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
[error]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:68)
[error]     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
[error]     at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:67)
[error]     at play.api.Play.start(Play.scala)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.start(Helpers.java:354)
[error]     at models.TagTest.setUpBeforeClass(TagTest.java:35)
```

Where line 35 is the line:

```
Helpers.start(app);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Use the debugger to see what value is `null`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `app` value is null. You should debug and figure out why it's null :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks from the stack like the NPE is thrown on **line 59** of your own `Global` class - inside your override of `GlobalSettings.onStart()`?

Look/debug there to see what the issue is. Hard to suggest any more without seeing your code - maybe [check this out](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal) for a basic intro to `Global` and how it can be used.

By the way - just a couple of additional points

- Why is `app` a static variable? It should probably be an instance variable of `TagTest`.
- You didn't have to point out what code was on line 35 of `TagTest` - this can be seen on the second-last line of the stacktrace. The first line of the trace shows you the method in which the Exception was actually thrown - the rest just show the stack of calls which led up to that method call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @davnicwil! Another member of my team had added that method and I was unaware that it was impacting my work. Effectively getting rid of that method for now has solved my issue.  

- I made the app variable static because of a suggestion I saw [here](http://blog.matthieuguillermin.fr/2012/03/unit-testing-tricks-for-play-2-0-and-ebean/) and because the Helpers.fakeApplication() method is a static one  

- Thanks for the heads up   :)

Comment: no probs, glad it was helpful :) Re `app` being a static variable, sure, it will work in this case just as well as an instance variable - more a matter of style really, I tend to avoid static variables wherever possible - but be aware that `Helpers.fakeApplication()` being a static method has no effect on the returned `FakeApplication` object reference - the method being static is just an incidental implementation detail meaning it 'belongs' to a Class rather than instances of that Class, and you can assign the returned value to `app` regardless of whether `app` is static or not.